# Creating an array of already existing labels in Java

Tags: java, arrays, label

So I'm writing a simple clicker game, which contains 9 different in-game items that have 3 properties that are displayed on labels. The GUI is already created and the labels named like "Item1Price", "Item1Count", etc.

On purchase/sale of these items (button click) the variables that display these properties are adjusted accordingly, but I'm left with a problem of labels which display those variables. In total that's 27 labels that need to be adjusted. Sure, I can reference them one-by-one, but there has to be a way for me to create an array of them, just like with numbers, such as :

`double itemPrice[] = {0.50, 2.50, 10.00};`

So can I have something along the lines of :

```
JLabel itemPropertyLabels[] = {Item1Price, Item2Price, Item3Price};
```

?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to change only 3? What does that have to do with an array?

Comment: I'm asking how I can **put my labels in an array**, so I can modify their texts with a loop, instead of writing a line for each label. Sorry, if the question was unclear

Comment: JLabel itemPropertyLabels[] = {new Item1Price(), new Item2Price(), new Item3Price()};